# python web-crawling error of 'no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am studying web crawling with selenium and I found some error.

This is my coding as follows.

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
main_url = 'https://searchad.naver.com/'
driver = wd.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
```

and I logged in

```
# access main url2

main_url2 = 'https://searchad.naver.com/my-screen'

# close popup window
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > my-app > wrap > welcome-beginner-layer-popup > div.ly_main_pop > div.pop_top > a').click() 

# main3 page access
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn_area>li').click()

# click tool menu bar
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#navbar-common-header-collapse > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a > span.ng-binding.ng-scope').click()
```

from the last coding(# click tool menu bar), there is a error as 
Error message:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. 
>   Both Css selector and xpath are errors.

This is the resources codes before I click the mouse on '도구' as follows.

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle ng-scope" ng-if="menu.items" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><!-- ngIf: menu.gnb != "billing" --><span ng-if="menu.gnb != &quot;billing&quot;" ng-bind-html="menu.translationId | translate" class="ng-binding ng-scope">도구</span><!-- end ngIf: menu.gnb != "billing" --><!-- ngIf: menu.gnb === "billing" --><span class="ico-dropdown-arrow"></span></a>

<!-- ngIf: menu.gnb != "billing" -->

<span ng-if="menu.gnb != &quot;billing&quot;" ng-bind-html="menu.translationId | translate" class="ng-binding ng-scope">도구</span>
```

After I click the menu '도구', I can find sub-menu of '키워드 도구'. This is also the codes of '키워드도구'.

```
<li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.items track by $index" ng-class="{ divider: submenu === &quot;divider&quot;, disabled: submenu.disabled }" class="ng-scope"><!-- ngIf: submenu.disabled --><!-- ngIf: submenu !== "divider" && !submenu.disabled --><a ng-if="submenu !== &quot;divider&quot; &amp;&amp; !submenu.disabled" data-click-logger="" data-click-id="click.tool.keyword-planner" href="/customers/668860/tool/keyword-planner" ui-sref="tool.keyword-planner(vm.getParams({customerId: customerId}, submenu.params))" ui-sref-opts="{reload: submenu.reload}" ng-bind-html="submenu.translationId | translate" class="ng-binding ng-scope">키워드 도구</a><!-- end ngIf: submenu !== "divider" && !submenu.disabled --></li>
<!-- ngIf: submenu.disabled -->
<!-- ngIf: submenu !== "divider" && !submenu.disabled -->
<a ng-if="submenu !== &quot;divider&quot; &amp;&amp; !submenu.disabled" data-click-logger="" data-click-id="click.tool.keyword-planner" href="/customers/668860/tool/keyword-planner" ui-sref="tool.keyword-planner(vm.getParams({customerId: customerId}, submenu.params))" ui-sref-opts="{reload: submenu.reload}" ng-bind-html="submenu.translationId | translate" class="ng-binding ng-scope">키워드 도구</a>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML for `#navbar-common-header-collapse > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a > span.ng-binding.ng-scope`

Comment: <span ng-if="menu.gnb != &quot;billing&quot;" ng-bind-html="menu.translationId | translate" class="ng-binding ng-scope">도구</span>

Comment: You just want to click on it , right ?

Comment: I want to click '도구' and scroll down and click '키워드 도구'. I want to chick '키워드 도구'

Answer (score 1):

For clicking on 도구 , you can try with this code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'도구')]")))  
element.click()
```

after this if you want to scroll down :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

Note that Y is the height on a full HD monitor it's 1080

and you can use same text method of xpath for selecting/clicking on web elements.

It's advisable to check the locator in dev tool, just to make sure that you have unique locator with you.

Import you will need :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried with the code, but there is an error as follows.  raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I think the menu of '도구' is hover menu.

Comment: Can you check, how many entries are present in dev tool for this `//span[contains(text(),'도구')]`

Comment: if it's a hover then you can use Actionchain from selenium to move the focus on that element.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will study hover and Actionchain. Even though the problem is not solved, I really thank you for your comment and help.

Comment: I do not have credential for the website , otherwise I would have looked into this matter personally.

Comment: I am in an early stage so I don't know how to have credential for the website. I will check it also and, if possible, I will make credential for the website. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure whether you understand me or not. Credentials are values which we use to login into website. That’s a confidential thing.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you for your explanation~!!